# Group by not working in Oracle -

Tags: oracle, group-by

When I run the below query it works fine

```
select  TO_CHAR(mydate ,'YYYYMMDD') , count(*) from table
where columnA = '123'
group by TO_CHAR(mydate,'YYYYMMDD')
```

But when I try to `order by` it fails

```
select  TO_CHAR(mydate ,'YYYYMMDD') , count(*) from table
where columnA = '123'
group by TO_CHAR(mydate,'YYYYMMDD')
order by mydate desc
```

[image]

Similarly when I try to do any arithmatic on the date I get the same error.

```
select  TO_CHAR(mydate +10/24 ,'YYYYMMDD') , count(*) from table
where columnA = '123'
group by TO_CHAR(mydate,'YYYYMMDD')
order by mydate desc
```

Can someone advise what is the best way to order by and add the 10 hours?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select  TO_CHAR(mydate ,'YYYYMMDD')  from table
where columnA = '123'
group by TO_CHAR(mydate,'YYYYMMDD')
order by mydate desc
```

ie, you need to put all the columns of your `select` in the `group by` to make it working.

**EDIT:-**

```
select  TO_CHAR(mydate ,'YYYYMMDD') , count(someID) from table
where columnA = '123'
group by TO_CHAR(mydate,'YYYYMMDD')
order by mydate desc
having count(someID)>1
```